How to limit btrfs-send throughput?
I am trying btrfs send/receive a 3TB btrfs volume.
When I sent it to another machine over network, it went fine. The speed was like 20-30 MB/s.
However, when the destination disk is directly attached to the source machine, btrfs send fails after sending like 200-250 GB with send ioctl failed with -5: Input/output error. The speed is above 200 Mb/s.
I checked the source filesystem, did btrfs scrub — all good.
I suspect the I/O error has something to do with trying to read the source too fast. So I would like to throttle it down to 20 Mb/s locally and try.
How can it be done?

The btrfs' send/receive commands are normally connected over a pipe |, thus the problem can be resolved with any method that can throttle pipes. I see that the btrbk backup application uses mbuffer to throttle transfer speed for example. Personally, I typically use pv when doing manual btrfs send/receive transfers where I want to limit the transfer speed:
# btrfs send /__snap/__example | pv -L 100M -q | ssh root@remote_host btrfs receive /srv/.

The btrfs send is first piped into pv which limits the speed before piping further to ssh. The pv parameters above are:

-L 100M ; or --rate-limit 100M (limit speed to 100 Megabytes/s)
-q ; or --quiet (don't print anything)

Alternatively instead of --quiet you could use the other feature of pv which prints a progress bar:

-p ; or --progress (Turn the progress bar on)
-s 64G ; or --size 64G (Assume the total amount of data to be transferred for calculating percentages and ETAs)


The error message normally indicates a hardware problem: disk or cables or ...
